# How to add osgEarth Features at runtime?

Tags: c++, openscenegraph, osgearth

I'm playing around with osgEarth and while it's crazy easy to add features in the .earth file, I'm struggling to do it at runtime via the API.  I want to let the user draw polygons on the map/globe so I need to be able to dynamically define geometry and styles based on user input.

Right now I'm just going for a static implementation to figure out what I need to do, but for the life of me I can't get anything to show up.  Here is my sample code.  I've already loaded a .earth file that defines the MapNode which is what I'm using here.

```
// Style
osgEarth::Symbology::Style shapeStyle;
shapeStyle.getOrCreate<osgEarth::Symbology::PolygonSymbol>()->fill()->color() = osgEarth::Symbology::Color::Green;

// Geometry
osgEarth::Symbology::Polygon* polygon = new osgEarth::Symbology::Polygon();
polygon->push_back(0, 0);
polygon->push_back(0, 10);
polygon->push_back(10, 10);

// Feature
osgEarth::Features::Feature* feature = new osgEarth::Features::Feature(polygon, mapNode->getMapSRS(), shapeStyle);

// Node
osgEarth::Annotation::FeatureNode* featureNode = new osgEarth::Annotation::FeatureNode(mapNode, feature);
featureNode->setStyle(shapeStyle);
featureNode->init();

mapNode->addChild(featureNode);
```

This *should* draw a green triangle near the middle of the map, but I don't see anything.  Am I wrong in assuming that my polygon points are geo coordinates (lon, lat)?  Is it wrong to just create my Style and Geometry on the fly like this?  What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: This seems to work fine on a 3D (geocentric) map, but not on a 2D (projected) map which is what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

After poking around a bit I stumbled upon the **osgearth_features** example that comes with the SDK which includes examples of creating features programatically.  I followed the pattern from the sample and came up with something that works.

```
// Style
osgEarth::Symbology::Style shapeStyle;
osgEarth::Symbology::PolygonSymbol* fillStyle = shapeStyle.getOrCreate<osgEarth::Symbology::PolygonSymbol>();
fillStyle->fill()->color() = osgEarth::Symbology::Color::Green;
osgEarth::Symbology::LineSymbol* lineStyle = shapeStyle.getOrCreate<osgEarth::Symbology::LineSymbol>();
lineStyle->stroke()->color() = osgEarth::Symbology::Color::Black;
lineStyle->stroke()->width() = 2.0f;

// Geometry
osgEarth::Symbology::Polygon* polygon = new osgEarth::Symbology::Polygon();
polygon->push_back(0, 0, 10000);
polygon->push_back(0, 10, 10000);
polygon->push_back(10, 10, 10000);

// Feature Options (references the geometry)
osgEarth::Drivers::OGRFeatureOptions featureOptions;
featureOptions.geometry() = polygon;

// Model Options (references the feature options and style)
osgEarth::Drivers::FeatureGeomModelOptions geomOptions;
geomOptions.featureOptions() = featureOptions;
geomOptions.styles() = new osgEarth::StyleSheet();
geomOptions.styles()->addStyle( shapeStyle );
geomOptions.enableLighting() = false;

// Model Layer Options (created using the model options)
osgEarth::ModelLayerOptions layerOptions("test polygon", geomOptions);
mapNode->getMap()->addModelLayer(new osgEarth::ModelLayer(layerOptions));
```

Defining the style and geometry is more or less the same as what I was doing before (I added a line symbol this time), but in this case I'm adding a ModelLayer to the Map.  That ModelLayer uses some model options that reference my style and geometry through the feature options.

I don't know if this is the *best* way to do it or how scalable it is (can I do this over and over thousands of times?), bit it's at least got me going,